# How to use multiple aggregate function with group by

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in advertiser,advertiser_clicks and advertiser_cost in which i have used join with multiple aggregate function.But i was unable to get the actual record from the tables.Please find below my table structure.

**Table1:advertiser**

```
................
id      name
................
1     Your Survey
2     Vindale
```

**Table2:advertiser_clicks**
In this table adv_id is foreign key of advertiser table **id**

```
.............................................................
id    adv_id    survey_id   survey_name  clicks  dt_datetime
.............................................................
1       1        101        survey1       1       2017-11-30
2       2        102        survey2       1       2017-11-29
3       1        103        survey3       1       2017-11-28
```

**Table3:advertiser_cost**
In this table a_click_id is the foreign key of advertiser_clicks table **adv_id**

```
.......................................................
ac_id   a_click_id   cpi    conversion  cost   profit  
......................................................
  1       1          10       1           8      2
  2       2          10       1           5      5
  3       3          5        1           5      5
```

**I want below output:**-when i select start date:2017-11-29 and enddate :2017-11-30 in where condition then i want below output.Here total click,cpi,cost & profit is the sum of all the data which comes in between that daterange.

```
.............................................................
adv_id    advertiser     totalclick    cpi    cost   profit
.............................................................
   1       Your survey       2          20     13     8
   2        vindale          0           0     0      0
```

I have write the below query which returns the exact data which comes
in between that date range but i it will not return the record of vindale
advertiser as a zero value.Please find my below query.

```
SELECT sum(advertiser_clicks.`clicks`) as totalclick,sum(advertiser_cost.cpi) as revenue,sum(advertiser_cost.`conversion`) as conversion,sum(advertiser_cost.`cost`) as cost,SUM(advertiser_cost.profit) as profit,advertiser.name as advertiser,advertiser.id as adv_id FROM `advertiser_clicks` LEFT JOIN advertiser_cost on advertiser_cost.a_click_id=advertiser_clicks.`id` inner join advertiser on advertiser.id=advertiser_clicks.`adv_id` where advertiser_clicks.`dt_datetime`>='2017-11-29' and advertiser_clicks.`dt_datetime`<='2017-11-30' group by advertiser.name,advertiser.id
```

My query return this output:-

```
.............................................................
adv_id    advertiser     totalclick    cpi    cost   profit
.............................................................
   1       Your survey       2          20     13     8
```

Comment: Why have you tagged both MySQL *and* SQL Server?

Comment: By mistake edit it to mysql only

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have resolved my issue:-

```
SELECT sum(advertiser_clicks.`clicks`) as totalclick,sum(advertiser_cost.cpi) as revenue,sum(advertiser_cost.`conversion`) as conversion,sum(advertiser_cost.`cost`) as cost,SUM(advertiser_cost.profit) as profit,advertiser.name as advertiser,advertiser.id as adv_id FROM `advertiser` left join advertiser_clicks on advertiser.id=advertiser_clicks.`adv_id` and (advertiser_clicks.`dt_datetime` between '$startdate' and '$enddate' ) LEFT JOIN advertiser_cost on advertiser_cost.a_click_id=advertiser_clicks.`id` group by advertiser.name,advertiser.id
```